# how to get value attribute of spinbox input for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-widgets

This is a basic jQuery question - 
I'm using the spinbox plugin, here:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="spin">Input spinner</label>
<input data-role="spinbox" name="spin" id="spin" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
</div>
```

updated value is shown correctly when clicking + or -,

but using this call...

```
$(this).replaceWith("<div>"+ $("#spin").val +"</div>" );
```

..returns garbage (code) and

```
$(this).replaceWith("<div>"+ $("#spin").value +"</div>" );
```

..returns "undefined"

I want to replace some element with the value of the spinbox. I'm assuming that the widget should make it this easy. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a method not a property, try the following:

```
$(this).replaceWith("<div>"+ $("#spin").val() +"</div>" );
```

*if you want to use `value` property you should convert the jQuery object to a DOM element:*

```
$("#spin")[0].value
```

Comment: Awesome. What does the index-0 represent? Anyways,  thanks a lot.

Comment: Many months later I can answer my own question (in above comment). Using Chrome's debugger to log that element to the console it is easily apparent that it contains an array and the DOM element at the 0th index has an attribute named 'value'.